# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 108: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, tensorflow-hub

Here is my code,

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
module_url = "C:/study/web_mystem_skipgram_500_2_2015.bin.gz"

# Import the Universal Sentence Encoder's TF Hub module
embed = hub.Module(module_url)
```

whenever I run this code it gives the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-92031fbf4749> in <module>
      2 
      3 # Import the Universal Sentence Encoder's TF Hub module
----> 4 embed = hub.Module(module_url)

D:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\module.py in __init__(self, spec, trainable, name, tags)
    155     """
    156     self._graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
--> 157     self._spec = as_module_spec(spec)
    158     self._trainable = trainable
.....
---> 78       self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
     79           self.__name, 1024 * 512)
     80 

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 108: invalid continuation byte
```

I can't find such problem solution with tensorflow_hub Module;
What should I do then! Please help.

Comment: for using text embeddings from universal sentence encoder please use :-

 # Import the Universal Sentence Encoder's TF Hub module
 
embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/1")


   //For the UnicodeDecodeError, your file doesn't seem to have UTF-8 data.